# Как заставить Jetty работать не по запросу?

Tags: java, сервер, spring, servlet, jetty

Самостоятельно изучаю Java, Jetty, Servlet. В дальнейшем хочу изучить Spring. Вот какой вопрос возникает: как заставить сервер выполнять постоянно или с какой-то периодичностью мой код без запроса клиента?
Например у меня есть датчики, с которых заранее самостоятельно нужно собрать информацию, а позднее, по запросу клиента только быстро вывести ее. Еще есть исполнительные устройства, которые нужно заставить работать без участия человека (открыть кран, включить вентиляцию).
В самом понятии Сервер заложено что он тупо ждет когда его дернут и по-другому не может. Я понимаю что можно заставить планировщик выполнять каждые пять секунд запрос на сервер, но это костыль, хотелось бы услышать правильное академичное решение, как это делают (например на предприятиях)?
Не хотелось бы перемещать ядро системы из Jetty в какое-то другое место или раздваивать логику выполняя посторонний скрипт.

Я еще не понял что такое application server, может быть он мне нужен? То есть может быть appserver отличается от обычного http-сервера и контейнера сервлетов тем, что умеет сам выполнять код по какому-то внутреннему расписанию и триггерам?

Быстрым взглядом на книжку по Спринг удалось заметить что там есть какие-то задачи и планировщик, может быть это то что мне нужно?

В дальнейшем я планирую использовать СУБД и клиента для Android, и может быть нет смысла держать логику моей программы (умного дома) в сервлетах, а стоит переместить ее во внешнюю программу или в СУБД, а Jetty оставить для отрисовки WEB-страниц? Как правильно сделать с точки зрения идеальной архитектуры (ведь СУБД может поменяться)?

Замечу еще, что всё это на древнем Raspberry Pi и много думаю использовать ли его как контроллер или все-таки как сервер. Можно прилично сэкономить на электричестве, а также легко выйти из ситуации заменив сбойное устройство и восстановив систему из резервной копии. К тому же такая система бесшумная.

Замену технологиям Java прошу не предлагать, выбор сделан (долго изучал популярность языков программирования и т.д.). Планы грандиозные, но по большому счету я новичок, прошу сильно умными словами не объясняться, если только по-другому никак.

Comment: Да. все верно, вам нужен планировщик. Прелесть Java-серверов в том, что они предоставляют лишь возможность внешним запросам пройти к вашему коду, а внутри у вас может быть что угодно, в том числе и тот самый планировщик (ScheduledExecutorService). Обратите внимание на пример @Constantine

Answer (score 3):

Нужно смотреть в стонону ServletContextListener и асинхронности. 
В ServletContextListener переопределить contextInitialized (запуск приложения) и в нем запускать нужный асинхронный таск:

```
public class BackgroundJobManager implements ServletContextListener {

    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SomeDailyJob(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        // или что-то вроде этого...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // убить таск при останове сервера:
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }

}
```

Разумеется, contextListener нужно зарегистрировать в web.xml.
Более полный пример можно найти тут: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-web-xml-configuration-example/

Comment: А что в jetty нет ManagedExecutorService, чтобы сразу, без шедулера через 1 день?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете spring обратите внимание на аннотацию `@Scheduled` она позволяет планировать запуск метода с различными настройками периодичности.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("The time is now " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Подробный [пример](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)